Scrolling the page cuts off boxes
I have the following boxes on a page. When I scroll down, there's a bug where the boxes are cut off so I can see the end of remaining boxes at the bottom. How can I write a playwright test to pick up that bug? I want to check to make sure the boxes load properly with being cut off on the page as you scroll down.

I tried the following
for (let x = 1; x < 6; x += 1) {
    const testBoxX = testBox + "-" + x;
    await test.testTile(testName).nth(0).scrollIntoViewIfNeeded({ timeout: 20000 });
    await expect(test.testTile(testName).nth(0)).toBeInViewport();
}


How about visual comparison https://playwright.dev/docs/test-snapshots#introduction ?

@hardkoded that won't work because the page is long. You can scroll to see many boxes.

Please share the page and your full automation code as a [mcve]. Without that, it's nearly impossible to help and I doubt you'll get any satisfactory answers to this. What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium? applies here, sub in Playwright for Selenium. Thanks.
